# Tensorflow: Invalid Argument Error in Convolution

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

I was trying to run this bit of Python code and can't seem to get around the error:

```
tf.nn.conv2d(tf.reshape(x, [5, 5]), tf.reshape(wt, [3, 3]), strides=[1, 1],  padding='SAME')
```

Here, x is a `tf.Variable` from a (5,5) numpy array and w is a tf.Variable from a (3,3) numpy array.

The error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
    669           node_def_str, input_shapes, input_tensors, input_tensors_as_shapes,
--> 670           status)
    671   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as err:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    468           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 469           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    470   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 2 for 'Conv2D_19' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [5,5], [3,3].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `tf.nn.conv2d`. both your input and filter should be transformed to a 4D. Also, `strides` should be `1-D of length 4` (sliding window for each one of the dimensions of the input). The following is taken from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d):

> Given an input tensor of shape [batch, in_height, in_width,
>   in_channels] and a filter / kernel tensor of shape [filter_height,
>   filter_width, in_channels, out_channels], this op performs the
>   following:
>
> Flattens the filter to a 2-D matrix with shape [filter_height *
>   filter_width * in_channels, output_channels]. Extracts image patches
>   from the input tensor to form a virtual tensor of shape [batch,
>   out_height, out_width, filter_height * filter_width * in_channels].
>   For each patch, right-multiplies the filter matrix and the image patch
>   vector.

You can take : `tf.reshape(x, [1, 5, 5, 1])` for the data, `tf.reshape(wt, [3, 3, 1, 1])` for the filter, and `strides=[1, 1, 1, 1]`. This results in:

```
tf.nn.conv2d(tf.reshape(x, [1, 5, 5, 1]), tf.reshape(wt, [3, 3, 1, 1]), strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],  padding='SAME')
```